# What is the foursquare providerId for instagram?

Tags: api, foursquare, instagram

I'm trying to harmonize my database's understanding of instagram venue id's with foursquare venue id's.

Answer (score 1):

Foursquare currently doesn't have an explicit providerId for Instagram. However, you can find Instagram location ID's given a Foursquare venue ID by using Instagram's /locations/search endpoint and passing in the `foursquare_v2_id` parameter: http://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/locations/

Comment: I should have clarified: I don't have the foursquare ID's at this time. What I have is a list of venues with lat/lng, name, and instagram location ID's. Is my best bet to just use the foursquare venue/search endpoint and give lat/lng + name, and use intent=match?

Comment: Ah, got it. Yes, to go from Instagram -> Foursquare, running a Foursquare search with the match intent is probably a good way about this problem.

Answer (score 1):

@octopi looks like instagram no longer uses `foursquare_v2_id` and replaced it with `FACEBOOK_PLACES_ID`